# Comparing 2D arrays of varying object type

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have written a method to compare different 2D Arrays and output whether they are the same or not using .equals. In my main tester class I am comparing two 2D Integer arrays to each other which are the same so the output should be 'true' and then two 2D String arrays which are different so the output should be false. When testing different combinations, when I test equal and unequal Integer arrays I get the correct output. Testing different size arrays, correct output and testing equal string arrays I get the correct output.

The issue I am having is the fact that when I test two unequal String arrays the program returns true when they are unequal so the output should be false. Thanks in advance for any help or tips.

```java
public boolean equals(Object[][] other) {
    boolean isEqual = false;

    if (myArray.length != other.length) {
        return isEqual;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (myArray[i][j].equals(other[i][j])) {
                isEqual = true;
            } else {
                isEqual = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

Testing:

```java
public class TwoDTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Initializing arrays
        Integer[][] firstArray = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
        Integer[][] secondArray = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};

        //Creating TwoDArray object for comparisons
        TwoDArray first = new TwoDArray(firstArray);

        //Testing true or false
        System.out.println(first.equals(secondArray));

        //Initializing more arrays
        String[][] thirdArray = {
                {"Hello", "Goodbye"},
                {"Hola", "Adios"},
                {"Bonjour", "Au revoir"}};

        String[][] fourthArray = {
                {"Hello", "Goodbye"},
                {"Ciao", "Addio"},
                {"Bonjour", "Au revoir"}};

        //Creating TwoDArray object for comparisons
        TwoDArray third = new TwoDArray(thirdArray);

        //Testing true or false
        System.out.println(third.equals(fourthArray));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you require every corresponding element in the arrays to be equal, then you should simply quit the loops when finding something unequal. For example you can `return false;` in that case, while returning `true` only if the loops finish (which would mean all corresponding elements are equal).

With your current code, only the last element is taken into account (which will overwrite the `isEqual` with whatever result is the equality of the last two elements), while all previous values will not be taken into account.

Also, if you allow `myArray` to contain `null` elements, then consider using [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) method to compare the objects for equality, but that's just a hint and not really related to the immediate problem.

As [pointed out by @Jems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744323/comparing-2d-arrays-of-varying-object-type/65744402#comment116240232_65744402), is should also be noted that in the following lines:

```
if (myArray.length != other.length)
{
    return isEqual;
}
```

you are testing for equality only the number of rows each 2D array has. Note that you should also probably be comparing each row of each array for equality between their columns. For example something like:

```
if (myArray[i].length != other[i].length)
    return false;
```

Not to mention the arrays being `null` themselves should be checked (that is both `myArray`, `myArray[i]`, `other` and `other[i]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can take the code of the [`Arrays.equals`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1856) method and customize it so that it accepts 2D arrays:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] one = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, null};
    Integer[][] two = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, null};

    String[][] three = {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}, {"E", null}};
    String[][] four = {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}, {"E", null}};

    System.out.println(equals2D(one, two)); // true
    System.out.println(equals2D(three, four)); // true
}
```

```java
/**
 * The two 2D arrays are equal if they contain the same rows
 * in the same order. Also, two array references are considered
 * equal if both are 'null'.
 */
public static boolean equals2D(Object[][] a1, Object[][] a2) {
    if (a1 == a2) return true;

    if (a1 == null || a2 == null || a1.length != a2.length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
        if (!equals1D(a1[i], a2[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

```java
/**
 * The two rows are equal if they contain the same elements
 * in the same order. Also, two row references are considered
 * equal if both are 'null'.
 */
public static boolean equals1D(Object[] a1, Object[] a2) {
    if (a1 == a2) return true;

    if (a1 == null || a2 == null || a1.length != a2.length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
        if (!Objects.equals(a1[i], a2[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```